# Add row to result set without using union mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to add a dummy row at the end of result set in mysql without using UNION[ALL].

I know mysql doesn't support full joins, so the hack would not work here.

I've tried my best but couldn't get any idea?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any SQL and you didn't mention the content of the dummy row, I can only guess that you might be solving some kind of SQL puzzle and are ready for any solution even an ugly one.

Beside `UNION` the only way I can think of to add a dummy row is with a `GROUP BY` clause and a [`ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).  So here is a rather clumsy way to do that :

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(id, 'Dummy1') as First,
  IFNULL(product, 'Dummy2') as product,
  IFNULL(price, 'Dummy3') as price,
  IFNULL(qty, 'Dummy4') as qty,
  IFNULL(barcode, 'Dummy5') as Last
FROM 
  products
GROUP BY 
  id, product, price, qty, barcode
WITH ROLLUP 
HAVING 
  Last <> 'Dummy5' or First = 'Dummy1'
```

Try it for yourself with this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qtMGHYLjCNBBZjqe9gNnZy/0)...